# After upgrading report portal 5.6.3 to 5.8.0(23.1) service-api:5.8.0 is becoming unhealthy intermittently and reportportal is going down after that

Tags: reportportal

Expected behavior
report portal should work as expected without any error with all the container healthy after upgradation to 23.1

Showing below exceptions in logs

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: Overriding serialized class version mismatch: local serialVersionUID = 550 stream serialVersionUID = com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.util.AuthUtils$SerialUidReplacingInputStream.readClassDescriptor(AuthUtils.java:105)

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException

com.epam.ta.reportportal.exception.ReportPortalException: com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException: Continuation call for method #method<channel.open>(out-of-band=) on channel AMQChannel

Versions:
5.8.0(23.1)

    java.io.InvalidClassException: Overriding serialized class version mismatch: local serialVersionUID = 550 stream serialVersionUID = 520
at com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.util.AuthUtils$SerialUidReplacingInputStream.readClassDescriptor(AuthUtils.java:105)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1992)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:929)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1046)

com.epam.ta.reportportal.exception.ReportPortalException: com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException: Continuation call for method #method<channel.open>(out-of-band=) on channel AMQChannel timed out
at com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.analyzer.auto.impl.LogIndexerService.indexLaunchLogs(LogIndexerService.java:109)
at com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.analyzer.auto.impl.LogIndexerService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f53c9b3b.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException: Continuation call for method #method<channel.open>(out-of-band=) on channel AMQChannel timed out
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:69)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1408)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.access$200(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1394)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:696)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:679)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:649)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1600(CachingConnectionFactory.java:99)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1413)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting the issue.
There is is already a ticket created by the community:
https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/issues/1970

If you face any issue with ReportPortal, please submit a ticket to [ReportPortal on GitHub](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/issues). StackOverflow isn't intended to be issue management system and not actively monitored by ReportPortal team.